# What's wrong with my Chef Configuration?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, cookbook

Chef newb here - trying to setup a development box using vagrant to work with ruby on rails.  I am digging through the docs, but can't seem to figure out the syntax around this error:

```
==> default: could not find recipe server for cookbook mysql
```

Here's the VagrantFile/Cheffile: https://gist.github.com/tlaffoon/593077d63e3c92b3acf5

I know I need to include the following, just not sure how:

[image: cheflink]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following two lines from your Vangrantfile (L33,34)

```
chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"
```

Mysql cookbook changed versions recently. The new version (6.0) doesn't provide recipes, just LWRP (`mysql_service` resource).

Then create your own cookbook (`knife cookbook create myname`) and add the mysql_service block to `cookbooks/myname/recipes/default.rb`